# Understanding Spring Boot auto-configuration behavior

Tags: dom, configuration, spring-boot

Spring Boot [docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-understanding-auto-configured-beans) contain the following phrase:

> You can browse the source code of spring-boot-autoconfigure to see the
>   @Configuration classes that we provide (see the
>   META-INF/spring.factories file).

How does one browse the specified source, should that be made into a browsable link in the docs?

Appreciate any additional reading materials on how auto-configuration machinery works in Spring Boot.  Thanks!

Comment: Either use your IDE or go to https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot

Comment: I'm not sure why we don't link to the source. I've opened https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/3767. Thanks for the suggestion.